# Can not distribute IPA file to App Store from Xamarin VS 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on Vs 2019 Xamarin on windows 10 paired to MAC mini (MacOS Catalina 10.15.1), XCode (11.2.1),

[I config all required certificates and profiles needed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows)

I do the following :

right-click on project and choose **Archive**
 
 In **Archive Manager** I choose **Distribute ...** 
 App store -> then select my (Signing Identity) and (Provisioning Profile) then **Upload to Store**

Then Vs crash and show the following error message

> Publishing project 'myapp' completed with errors. Could not create ipa
>   file for distribution of the archive 'myapp' Unable to copy file
>   "C:\Users\SWE_A\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch\Archives\2019-11-26\myapp.iOS
>   11-26-19 2.22
>   PM.xcarchive\mSYMs\myapp.iOS.app.mSYM\35a1689918aaa1797d4e3a9c36ba5791\Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.dll.msym"
>   to "obj\iPhone\Release\archives\myapp.iOS 11-26-19 2.22
>   PM.xcarchive\mSYMs\myapp.iOS.app.mSYM\35a1689918aaa1797d4e3a9c36ba5791\Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.dll.msym".
>   The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change the source to C:/ drive or D:/ drive (or another location with fewer characters in the path) or install the long path tool.

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs , the problem should be the **Paths** . Here is a good discussion for reference .

About [the Fully Qualified path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths)  , you can have a look at this document ,it results of the **[Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation)** problems .

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is **MAX_PATH**, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string" where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)

**Therefore** , suggest that moving project to the short root folder path , such as `C:\` . Better not more than three levels of file level .